# Where are the different versions of localtime_s used in C?

Tags: c, time, localtime

I have been compiling someone else's code in VS2017, and stumbled across this warning:

> Warning   C4996 'localtime': This function or variable may be unsafe.
>   Consider using localtime_s instead. To disable deprecation, use
>   _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

So I have looked up `localtime_s` and found it... twice:

[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/localtime)

```
struct tm *localtime_s(const time_t *restrict time, struct tm *restrict result);
```

[msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a442x3ye.aspx)

```
errno_t localtime_s(  
   struct tm* _tm,  
   const time_t *time   
);
```

Obviously, these are different. So now I wonder, if I replace `localtime` by Microsoft's `localtime_s`, who will be able to compile this code, and who won't? Isn't C standardized?

Comment: Both of these links point to documentation for C (not C++), and the first one even mentions that it's been introduced in C11 (which Microsoft's compiler is not fully compliant with)

Comment: Microsoft added its "safe" functions before they were standardized, and now there's a mismatch.

Comment: Your other option is to add `#define  _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to your project and have the warnings go away without any other changes.